# MdotM failure with adwhirl

Tags: adwhirl

I used Adwhirl_3.1.1 (admob+inmobi+mdotm) for may app and everything works fine except MdotM...The log appears as follows...

```
D/MdotM SDK (MdotMView)( 3656): HTTP/1.1 200 OK
D/MdotM SDK (MdotMView)( 3656): Neglecting, Invalid AD response.
W/MdotM SDK (MdotMView)( 3656): Ad is not loaded
D/AdWhirl SDK( 3656): MdotM failure
D/AdWhirl SDK( 3656): Showing ad:
D/AdWhirl SDK( 3656):   nid: ####
D/AdWhirl SDK( 3656):   name: mdotm
D/AdWhirl SDK( 3656):   type: 12
D/AdWhirl SDK( 3656):   key:#####
D/AdWhirl SDK( 3656):   key2: 
D/AdWhirl SDK( 3656): Generic adapter will get destroyed
D/AdWhirl SDK( 3656): Valid adapter, calling handle()
D/MdotM SDK (MdotMView)( 3656):   fetching Ad started 
D/MdotM SDK( 3656): ######
```

Could you suggest any solutions for this issue...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a specific issue with MDotM.  AdWhirl is calling MDotM to make the request, but MDotM is failing for some reason.  From a similar discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/adwhirl-users/Xw3mQS8FfkU), it looks like MDotM has a problem locking control of the program.